# Joomla index.html file

Tags: joomla

Why is there an **index.html** file in almost every folder in Joomla? What folders do not contain an **index.html** file and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blank index.html file in each folder is to prevent directory browsing via web address.

On a poorly configured web server someone could see all the files contained in a folder by simply browsing to the path, such as www.yoursite.com/images/, this could be a potential security problem on servers without directory browsing (indexing) turned off.

Having the blank index.html file returns a blank white screen to the browser rather than displaying the contents of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The index.html file isn't necessary, it's in the folders as a layer of security. It is there to keep prying eyes from being able to see a directory structure, if there was no index.html file and someone randomly went to `http://yoursite.com/scripts/js/` (for example), they could potentially see a listing of all files in that directory. Instead, with the index.html file in place they see a blank landing page:

`<html><body bgcolor=" #FFFFFF" ></body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (for apache servers) is to add this line to the .htaccess file placed at the root directorty of the website:

Options -Indexes

It prevents directory browsing for the whole website.